# How to post text with media for tweepy and the new API v2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

Recently, the twitter developer API has not shown an option to apply for Elevated Access. This means I am stuck with the free version of API v2. Now, I am trying to post a tweet with some text as well as an image. There is a parameter in create_tweet() called media_ids, but the problem is that there is no media_upload() for me to get a media id. I assume this is due to API changes, more specifically, the deprecation of Elevated Access. How would I be able to post text and an image form a path?
Here is my Python code:

```py
import tweepy
import keys # This is my python script that contains my dev keys.

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=keys.api_key,
                       consumer_secret=keys.api_secret,
                       access_token=keys.access_token,
                       access_token_secret=keys.access_token_secret,
                       bearer_token=keys.bearer_key)

def tweet(client: tweepy.Client, message: str, media_path=None):
    client.create_tweet(text=message) 
    # How would I upload media ^^^ here from a path in the current directory?
    print("Tweet tweet!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_message = "I love cats and dogs!"
    tweet(client=client, message=my_message, media_path="pets.png")
```

PS: I am using the latest version of tweepy and python3 respectably.

I looked online to see if there were any problems with applying for Elevated Access, or if it was just something on my end. I could not find anything substantive enough, so I came here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code earlier today from another user. Works perfectly for me

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import API

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""


def get_twitter_conn_v1(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret) -> tweepy.API:
    """Get twitter conn 1.1"""

    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(
        access_token,
        access_token_secret,
    )
    return tweepy.API(auth)

def get_twitter_conn_v2(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret) -> tweepy.Client:
    """Get twitter conn 2.0"""

    client = tweepy.Client(
        consumer_key=api_key,
        consumer_secret=api_secret,
        access_token=access_token,
        access_token_secret=access_token_secret,
    )

    return client

client_v1 = get_twitter_conn_v1(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
client_v2 = get_twitter_conn_v2(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)


media_path = "C:\\YourPath"

media = client_v1.media_upload(filename=media_path)
media_id = media.media_id

client_v2.create_tweet(text="This is a test", media_ids=[media_id])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).